# watching return-values in Visual Studio Code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, return-value, watch

When debugging, is it possible to watch return-values in VSC? and how?
I can't find an option to watch auto-variables like Visual Studio has

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio Code recently supported this - the returned value can be found under "Local":
[image]

Comment: Hi! Did they support it for all languages? It doesn't show up for my python project. Where can I get this info from? I searched and didn't find anything...

Comment: I don't know, It just starts working for Node.js after a version-update

Answer (score 10):

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_44.md#reference-returnvalue-in-watches-and-debug-console  JAVASCRIPT

With v1.44:

> **Reference $returnValue in Watches and Debug Console**
>
> When it's availble in the callstack, you can now reference the
>   function's `$returnValue` in the debug console and watch expressions.

So it can be used in the Watch view and the debug console.

[image: return value]